# root index crossed by root sign [at a very large font size]

Tags: root, yhmath

I came across with a problem when calling the `yhmath` package in a 17pt-letter-size document of the `extarticle` document class.

The index is crossed by the line of the very sign of the root.

It's easy to avoid it just by using a `phantom` character.

The problem is not happening with 11pt size anymore.

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[n]{\frac{a}{b}} %the problem is showed here
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[3\phantom{1}]{\frac{10}{5}} %the problem is solved here
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I show you the problem:

[image: Problem reported]

As I'm new in this, i don't know if report to the creator of the package in order to get it fixed or just leave here the message for you the experts to decide if I'm right or I'm wrong.

The aim is just to help any other users.

Comment: Why do you need a 17 pt font size?

Comment: I don't see why should it be useful but anyway. I want a kind of slides document, but i don't want to get it by beamer. I want an a4 landscape document with a 17pt size letter. When sheets are projected on a canvas i don't need to pay attention to the zoom, i get the right ratio instantly. I would appreciate any helping comment that makes my work better. Should you have any, don't hesitate to share. Thanks.

Comment: It is important because if you show the slide in fullscreen then the actual paper size doesn't matter. You can use a smaller paper size and use the default font size. This is why Beamer works without a problem in this regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have tools from `amsmath` to adjust the placement of root orders, `\leftroot` and `\uproot`:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[\leftroot{3}\uproot{3}n]{\frac{a}{b}} %the problem is showed here
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[\leftroot{3}\uproot{3}3]{\frac{10}{5}} %the problem is solved here
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew this. I think it's quite useful.

Comment: Yes. It's not a specific problem of `yhmath`. It also happens with Computer Modern.

Comment: @Aweraka You can accept this answer if it solved your problem (see left side of the answer).

Answer (score 5):

- I recommend that you use the default font size.
- **Change the paper size instead.**
- This way you do not have to micro management the positioning.
- The effect is the same (for your use case: presentation).
- This is less likely to have unanticipated side effects (the `beamer` document class also uses this approach).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth = 120mm, paperheight = 90 mm, margin=5mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[n]{\frac{a}{b}} % NO problem is shown here
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[3\phantom{1}]{\frac{10}{5}} % not needed anymore
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]